Handle invalid property value in a custom Control with data binding
Let's say you are creating a custom control with properties that the user may be able to change (either at design time, or during run time), and the property values must fall within specific boundaries. In addition, some or all of these properties may be bound to a Business Object.
If you were to implement some verification logic within a property setter in your custom control that will eventually be bound in a consuming form or composite control, and your logic ignores or modifies the value being set, then the property in your control will become out of sync with the binding Business Object. You may instead throw an exception within the setter which then puts the responsibility of validation on the calling code, although there's some debate about whether or not this is appropriate. Or, you may accept the value regardless but then place the control in an invalid state, indicating this to the user.
Another (perhaps, sanctioned) method is by doing Input Validation. In Microsoft's User Input Validation in Windows Forms, there is a section titled Event-driven validation data-bound controls which addresses the data binding aspect, however a couple of issues with this article is that it appears to apply to the Form domain rather than the Control domain, and only when input is going from Control to Business Object, rather than the other way around.
You would likely want to validate the data within the business object before the data is bound to your control, but what if you can't do that? How can a custom control enforce rules over its own properties, while maintaining synchronization with the data binding?
Possible strategies

Fail hard and fast: Throw an exception from the setter so calling code knows right away that something went wrong. This could be good for scenarios where your control's properties may be bound (see How can I catch an Exception triggered by databound Control?), although I'm not sure how this impacts the VS Designer.
Automatically fix the problem: Quietly change either the value being set, or a conflicting property. Microsoft does this for their TrackBar Maximum and Minimum properties. The immediate drawback I see about this is that dependent code (bound objects or parent controls) isn't aware of the changes unless it explicitly checks afterwards.
Shadow fields/properties: For important and interdependent properties, a second set of fields can be created for each one, which represent the relevant property's value after it's been validated against the rest of the object state. These fields are the ones that the rest of the control refers to.

See Also

StackOverflow Adding validation in WinForms without IDataErrorInfo
StackOverflow What are the common practices for notifying a user of invalid input?
StackOverflow Databinding to a custom control
StackOverflow Using a BindingSource in a UserControl
StackOverflow Correct way to Handle Exceptions in UserControl
StackOverflow Validating custom Editing Control in DataGridView

